# Get a list of all available fields in the User Profile

Tags: functions, custom-field, users, profiles

By default, the **User Profile** page has a few options and fields that the user can set. Such as the following:

```
Personal Options
-- Visual Editor
-- Admin Color Scheme
-- Keyboard Shortcuts
-- Toolbar
Name
-- First Name
-- Last Name
-- Nickname
-- Display Name
Contact Info
-- Website
About Yourself
-- Biographical Info
-- Avatar Display
```

In my plugin, [**Disable Blogging**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-blogging/), I've added a settings page which lists all of these fields in checkboxes to toggle which ones to hide ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls245.png)).

However, depending on the plugin or theme you're using, there will be additional settings and fields that will be shown. Take the [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin as an example, which adds these [extra fields under the Contact Info section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cb9a.png) and a section of their own:

```
Contact Info
-- Website
-- Google+
-- Twitter username (without @)
-- Facebook profile URL
...
Yoast SEO
-- Title to use for Author page
-- Meta description to use for Author page
-- Exclude user from Author-sitemap
-- Disable SEO analysis
-- Disable readability analysis
```

Using the [`wp_get_user_contact_methods()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_user_contact_methods/) function, I was able to easily `echo` a list of the custom contact fields that were added by the [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) plugin like so:

```
add_action( 'personal_options', 'wpse_237504_user_profile_fields' );
function wpse_237504_user_profile_fields() {
    foreach ( wp_get_user_contact_methods() as $id => $label ) {
        echo( $label . " > " . $id . "<br>" );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Google+ > googleplus
Twitter username (without @) > twitter
Facebook profile URL > facebook
```

Unfortunately, I do not see a native WordPress function I can call to get all of the fields listed in the User Profile.

The [Disable Blogging](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-blogging/) plugin hides these fields is by using JavaScript based on the `for=` values set in each `<label>`. For example: `<label for="user_login">Username</label>`

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    $( 'form#your-profile > h2' ).hide();
    <?php
        foreach ( $profile_fields as $label ) {
            echo( "$( '#" . $label . "' ).closest( 'tr' ).hide(); " );
        }
    ?>
    } );
</script>
<?php
```

---

#### Overall Goal

While this works for all of User Profile fields that I've manually listed in the plugin, my overall goal for this question is automatically get a list of all available fields (both native and custom) in the User Profile without having to manually list them in my plugin.

This way, when a user who is using the [Disable Blogging](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-blogging/) plugin, want to hide profile files that were created by another plugin or theme, it will be automatically listed as a checkbox.

---

While I'm not asking for anyone to write the whole code for me (*though I won't mind either and be happy to add you as a contributor*), I'll accept partial answers to help me complete this function or show me an alternative way to get the same results.

If there is something you're not clear of, drop a comment or message me on [The Loop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/) for a faster response

Comment: Using `preg_match` to find `<label>` tags in the html will work, but theoretically it is possible to include two `<label>` tags as a result of one meta field. So whether this result is water tight depends on the ultimate goal of your list: do you want the database fields or the displayed input fields?

Comment: @cjbj I want to display the input fields. What do you mean by this statement? `...it is possible to include two <label> tags as a result of one meta field.`

Comment: The html to be displayed on the profile page is generated by the plugin that defines the field. The plugin may decide to hide the field or to generate two labels or whatever. It's not very likely, but not impossible either.

Comment: @cjbj Okay, from testing I haven't run into that issue yet, so I'm not concerned about that at the moment.

Comment: I would not go with the labels and especially not with a Regex. Use `\DomDocument` and a XPath query if you really want to do it that way.

Comment: Not all these are stored in user meta, and so they might not be 'fields' as such, since they're special and stored in the user table itself

Comment: @kaiser That's just one possible way I would know how to get the data, but if there is a better way to retrieve the fields, I'm open to an alternative. I've updated my question for more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter in [`get_user_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) is optional, so you can retrieve all user meta like this (code tested quickly in my install):

```
$cu = get_current_user_id ();
$um = get_user_meta ($cu);
var_dump ($um);
```

This would also include meta fields that are hidden on the user profile page.

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, as you mentioned, this returns all of the hidden metadata that I don't want. Also, I it looks like that this won't work in getting the label of each field (ex: `user_login` = `Username`), unless I'm wrong.

Comment: My guess would be that the label is in some way automatically derived from one of the metafields. But I didn't check.